# Calling external programs using python

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7

How to call an external program in Linux and also pass some arguments to it?
For example I want to open 'nedit' in Linux and pass some text there..
Is it possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling an external command in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

import os
command = r'.../...externalProgram'
os.system(command)

or

import subprocess
command = r'.../...externalProgram'
subprocess.run(command)